# How do I use "AR API" of FI -Ware?

Tags: augmented-reality, fiware

I found very little information on the API augmented reality FI- WARE . Anyone know of some tutorial or some example of how it work ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a short summary of augmented reality GE available in the FIWARE Academy:
https://edu.fiware.org/course/index.php